# Não commitar linha específica no Git

Tags: git

É possível no Git ignorar uma linha específica dentro de um arquivo?

Seria interessante para casos onde precisamos registrar uma senha, neste caso preciso commitar o arquivo, mas gostaria de ignorar a linha que contem a senha.

Comment: Sim, é possível. A maioria das ferramentas permite decidir que linhas farão parte de cada commit. Você faz um commit apenas com as mudanças que quer e as demais linhas ficam pendentes.

Answer (score 3):

Como já dito na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/127492/112052), basta usar `git add -p arquivo`.

Mas [nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127196/n%c3%a3o-comitar-linha-espec%c3%adfica-no-git#comment268200_127492) foi pedido um exemplo mais detalhado de como fazer, então vamos lá (*testes feitos com Git 2.37.3, pode ser que em outras versões algumas mensagens sejam diferentes*).

---

Supondo que tenho este arquivo no meu repositório (já devidamente *commitado*):

```
abc
def
ghi
```

Agora eu adicionei algumas linhas nele:

```
abc
def
ghi
nova linha 1
nova linha 2
nova linha 3
nova linha 4
nova linha 5
```

Mas eu só quero adicionar as linhas 1, 4 e 5 no próximo commit.
Então eu faço `git add -p arquivo` e aparece algo assim:

```bash
git add -p arquivo 
diff --git a/arquivo b/arquivo
index 8edb37e..8bbff57 100644
--- a/arquivo
+++ b/arquivo
@@ -1,3 +1,8 @@
 abc
 def
 ghi
+nova linha 1
+nova linha 2
+nova linha 3
+nova linha 4
+nova linha 5
(1/1) Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,e,?]?
```

Ele mostra as linhas adicionadas (indicando isso com um `+` no início), e pergunta o que fazer. Você pode digitar `?` e <kbd>ENTER</kbd> para mais detalhes, e vai aparecer algo assim:

```bash
y - stage this hunk
n - do not stage this hunk
q - quit; do not stage this hunk or any of the remaining ones
a - stage this hunk and all later hunks in the file
d - do not stage this hunk or any of the later hunks in the file
e - manually edit the current hunk
? - print help
```

**O Git chama todo o trecho modificado de *hunk*** (literalmente um "pedaço", mas vou usar o nome em inglês daqui pra frente). Veja que você pode optar por adicionar tudo (`y`), mas aí ele vai adicionar as 5 linhas. Também pode ignorar com `n`, e aí ele vai para o próximo *hunk* - nesse caso só tem um, mas poderia ter mais (inclusive, se você rodar apenas `git add -p`, ele iria para o próximo arquivo, por exemplo). Também pode encerrar tudo com `q`.

Mas no caso queremos escolher quais modificações queremos enviar, então a opção a ser escolhida é `e` (editar manualmente o *hunk*). Ao digitar `e` e <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, ele abre o editor com o seguinte:

```bash
# Manual hunk edit mode -- see bottom for a quick guide.
@@ -1,3 +1,8 @@
 abc
 def
 ghi
+nova linha 1
+nova linha 2
+nova linha 3
+nova linha 4
+nova linha 5
# ---
# To remove '-' lines, make them ' ' lines (context).
# To remove '+' lines, delete them.
# Lines starting with # will be removed.
# If the patch applies cleanly, the edited hunk will immediately be marked for staging.
# If it does not apply cleanly, you will be given an opportunity to
# edit again.  If all lines of the hunk are removed, then the edit is
# aborted and the hunk is left unchanged.
```

Repare que para remover linhas que foram adicionadas (as que começam com `+`), basta apagá-las (*To remove '+' lines, delete them*). No caso, eu quero que apenas as linhas 1, 4 e 5 estejam no próximo commit, então basta apagar as linhas 2 e 3, ficando assim:

```bash
# Manual hunk edit mode -- see bottom for a quick guide.
@@ -1,3 +1,8 @@
 abc
 def
 ghi
+nova linha 1
+nova linha 4
+nova linha 5
```

Basta salvar e pronto. Se não tiverem mais *hunks* a serem analisados, o comando se encerra. Caso tenha, seja no mesmo arquivo, ou em outro arquivo se você fez apenas `git add -p` (ou ainda `git add -p arquivo1 arquivo2 etc`), ele mostra o próximo *hunk* e as opções já citadas acima (adicionar, pular, editar, etc).

A seguir, basta fazer o commit, e apenas as linhas 1, 4 e 5 estarão nele. Mas vale lembrar que as linhas 2 e 3 continuam no arquivo, então você ainda pode decidir enviá-las em um commit futuro.

Answer (score 1):

Ao adicionar o arquivo específico no *staging* (ou seja, o espaço de arquivos que entrarão no próximo *commit*), adicione-o com:

```
git add -p <arquivo>
```

Dessa forma você pode selecionar os espaços contíguos de modificações no arquivo.

Comment: Ainda não consegui achar na documentação como fazer para selecionar partes do arquivo. Tem algum exemplo?