# Comandos Git: git add e git commit

Tags: git, github, comandos

Qual é a diferença entre comandos como git add e git commit?
Sei que o git add joga os arquivos em uma área chamada stage, ou index. Mas que diferença há entre essa área e o git commit?

Comment: *"Sei que o git add joga os arquivos em uma área chamada stage" e o `git commit` "prepara" tudo que está nesse "stage" para ser "enviado" ao repositório remoto com `git push`

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/481907/112052

Comment: Outros links relacionados que podem ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/326086/112052 | https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48602/112052 | https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127196/112052

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Quando utilizar o GIT ADD?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/481907/quando-utilizar-o-git-add)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git **add** adiciona arquivos modificados a uma área temporária, a *staging area*, sem que haja um comprometimento com a fixação dessas modificações. Arquivos podem ser adicionados ou removidos dessa área à revelia do desenvolvedor antes do comprometimento ocorrer.

Git **commit** (do inglês "comprometer-se"), como o próprio nome diz, se compromete com as modificações que foram adicionadas e gera um *commit*, que é um conjunto das diferenças existentes em relação a um *commit* anterior na árvore de versionamento.

Uma vez "commitado" o código, ele é "escrito em pedra". Você não apaga mais aquele *commit*, em princípio, e pode acessá-lo novamente (dar *checkout* no mesmo com **git checkout**) caso haja um *branch* (espécie de rótulo que indica um ramo) apontando para o mesmo ou para um de seus *commits*-filhos, ou se souber os primeiros dígitos do *hash* (código hexadecimal) que representa aquele *commit*.

Atente-se porém que se não houver um *branch* nessas condições o *commit* pode deixar de ficar visível para o desenvolvedor.

Como informação adicional (e muito útil), o comando **gitk --all** mostra de maneira visual os *commits* e *branches* do seu repositório.

Answer (score -2):

Olá! **git add** significa **Adicionar**, ou seja, você pode adicionar um arquivo qualquer.
Exemplo: git add nomedomeuarquivoaqui.

Já em **git commit** é muito importante, pois indica as alterações que você fez no seu projeto. Ou seja, o commit é a **realização de um conjunto de mudanças, alterações que você realizou em seu projeto**.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).